# Count Word of Rich Text Box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

I am very very new to SharePoint and working hard these days.  I have a list item named Story (Rich Text Box).  When the user types words in the column, below it I need to show the number of words typed in the editor.  I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Mavention Word Count solution (http://blog.mastykarz.nl/counting-words-mavention-word-count/)?